# Eclipse CDT 2018-09 (4.9.0) non functional GDB window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

The GDB debugger console window in Eclipse CDT 2018-09 (4.9.0) on Windows doesn't appear to be functional when debugging remote Linux targets.

We can start the debugger (over ssh) and see output from the program in the console window. Likewise the gdb debugger console window appears, but it never shows any output, and we cannot enter gdb commands into it.

Expected behavior:

- Start debugger, gdb debug console window displays with interactive gdb session (gdb output appears and we can enter gdb commands).

Actual behavior:

- Start debugger, gdb debug console exists but appears inoperable.

We are building an embedded Linux program on Windows using cross compilers.

When we debug the program on the remote target, we need to use the gdb console to manually load shared libraries using the "sharedlibrary" command so that we can step through shared libraries that get loaded by the main program.

However, on recent versions of Eclipse, the gdb console window displays, but is otherwise inoperable. There is no gdb output and we cannot interact with it / enter commands.

I've found some very old topics similar to this but this is on a very recent Eclipse CDT build 2018-09 (4.9.0)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was with the DevStyle color theme plugin the developer was using. The DevStyle theme (https://www.genuitec.com/products/devstyle/) was hosing the debug window. Disabling the theme (reverting to standard) resolved the issue.